# How to get variable from AppController beforeFilter in Other Controllers action in cakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have queried on the User table inside the AppController as below

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter() {

        function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')) {
                $userLoginInfo = $this->User->findByUserId($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
                $this->set('userLoginInfo', !empty($userLoginInfo) ? $userLoginInfo : NULL);
            }
        }

    }

}
?>
```

The `$userLoginInfo` is available in all `ctp` files, but I want to access it in all other controller actions as well.

Answer (score 4):

now you put this code in `AppController`

```
function beforeFilter(){
$this->set(‘accesstest’ , ‘abc’);
}
```

And We have to use it in Other controller file say `anotherController.php`

then we will use $this->viewVars.

here we will be used

```
$test  = $this->viewVars[‘accesstest’];
$this->set('test',$test);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31108691/311992) is applicable if wanting to set a variable for all Views, but this was not what you were asking in your question.

If you are extending `AppController` correctly then you can create a property of the `AppController` class that would then be accessible from any controller that extends it:-

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $accesstest = 'abc';
}
```

Then in any controller that extends `AppController` you can use:-

```
$test = $this->accesstest;
echo $test; // 'abc'
```

However, if you want to share a variable that you want accessible from all controllers that can be changed and you want the change remembering then use the Session:-

```
$this->Session->write('accesstest', 'abc');
$test = $this->Session->read('accesstest');
```

Comment: How we will do the same in cakephp 3.6

Comment: @GYaN you can get the session object via the request in CakePHP 3: `$this->request->session()`. Otherwise everything else should work the same.

Comment: I want like : I can save $this->request->session() in a variable in AppController and use the session by calling this variable by any controller. How can I do that.

Comment: Hi @GYaN, I'd recommend starting a new question for this so that you can elaborate on what you need. Share the link to the question here and I'll try and help. 

Answer (score 1):

```
$userLoginInfo =  $this->viewVars['userLoginInfo'];
```